# Retagging recursion-theory to computability?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

It seems worth adding recursion-theory as a synonym for computability.

Is there support for this?

(I don't meet the requirements to vote for this myself.)

Comment: Do want to make [recursion-theory] a synonym for [computability]? Strictly speaking there are differences between them, but probably they are not important here.

Comment: @Kaveh: What are the differences?  I was under the impression that computability theory was a perfect synonym for recursion theory (though of course the word "recursive" also has another meaning, as in "a function that calls itself").

Comment: once it has 4 votes, flag it and I'll add the synonym.  this is the policy we currently have in place.

Comment: @Joshua: There is a slight difference, see R. Soare's article "The History and Concept of Computability" in the Handbook of Computability Theory. But I think we can ignore the difference on this site, so I support making them synonyms.

Comment: @Kaveh: I see now.  Thanks for the reference.

Comment: All the uses so far of the tag have been for computability meant generally.  Soare's article was in fact one of my motivations behind the suggestion.

Comment: Andras, according to the privileges page, you should have moderator powers - can you really not vote on the synonym ?

Comment: [The page](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/tags/computability/synonyms) says "and a total answer score of 3 or more on the tag", so reputation alone (+2500) does not seem to be enough.

Comment: @Kaveh: I really liked the quote from Soare's article: it might be useful to keep it around?

Comment: @András Salamon: done.

Comment: +1.  Reached +4.  Flagged for moderator attention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is two paragraphs from the final section of Soare's article "The History and Concept of Computability" in the "Handbook of Computability Theory":

> The term and concept of "computable" is associated with the notion of computation, algorithm, and with the functions defined by (or sets
>   enumerated by) Turing machines or register machines ,
>   and also with relative Turing computability.
>   The term and concept of "recursive" is associated with: definition by recursion
>   (induction) , general recursive functions in the sense in Herbrand-Godel
>   , fixed points as in the Kleene Recursion Theorem or more generally
>   Kleene's schema , which Kleene believed included all possible recursions, and
>   Kleene's $\mu$-recursive functions.
>
> Researchers in the subject have recently changed the the name of the subject
>   from "Recursion Theory" to "Computability Theory" in order to make clear this
>   distinction. Thus, the term "recursive" no longer carries the additional meaning of
>   "computable" or "decidable," as it once did. This reinforces the original meaning
>   of "recursive" and induction as understood by Dedekind [1888], Peano [1889] and
>   [1891], Hilbert [1904] and [1926], Skolem [1923], Godel [1931] and [1934], and
>   Peter [1934] and [1951], and by most modem computer scientists, mathematicians,
>   and physical scientists, and as expanded to fixed points, the recursion theorem, and
>   to other kinds of recursion by Kleene, Platek, and others.
>   Presently, if functions are defined, or sets are enumerated, or relative computability
>   is defined using Turing machines, register machines, or variants of these (as in the
>   texts in Table 1 of Section 4.6 or in the Putnam [1995] review), then the name "computable" rather than "recursive" will be attached to the result, as in Cutland [1980],
>   Davis [1958], as well as [Boolos and Jeffrey, 1974], the subtitle of [Soare, 1987] and
>   others